# Determining the equation of a cooling tower(a hyperboloid of one sheet)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Mathematics has a lot of applications recently i found out through Calculus that we find equation of cooling towers usually used in nuclear plants since they are in shape of a hyperboloid. I was working on one example on finding the mathemtical equation of a hyperboloid of one sheet and showing that certain points lies on the equation found. The question is in this form.

Designing  a cooling tower in the shape of hyperboloid of one sheet. The horizontal cross sections of the cooling tower are circular with 10m.The cooling tower is 40m tall with maximum cross-sectional radius of 15m. Write the mathematical equation for the cooling tower. If 
$$
\begin{cases}
x=a \cos(u)\cosh(v) \\
y=b \sin(u)\cosh(v) \\
z= c\sinh(v)
\end{cases}
$$, show that

$(x,y,z)$ lies on your equation.

From calculus I  know the equation of a hyperboloid is $\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac {y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$ but I'm finding difficulty in applying the given parameters in the question.
Thank you

Comment: What's the difficulty you encountered? How I see it, is that you just have to confirm that the latter equation is correct. I mean, that the expression is equal to 1. So just insert the values of $x,y$ and $z$ and you should be done.

Comment: I tried to assume that the center is at the origin with z-axis and maimum cross-sectional radius is at  the centre meaning the equation above will be used. I tried to do traces which turned out to be circles  int the x-y plane which implies that $a =$b but my problem is with this part i don't think is right what do you reckon @MattiP.

Comment: When i did calculations I having difficulty in determining the $c$ i was getting a complex root

Comment: Why do you want to **determine** $c$ ? In the latter equation, you divide by $c$ and it gets cancelled away ...

Comment: Can you elaborate more how it is cancelled I'm not getting it